# Reverse for 'article-create' not found. 'article-create' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I started getting this error all of the sudden.

**I don't have any thing related to article-create in my urls.py or models.py or views.py**

After adding the below code:
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, default=False)

and the below related i encountered this error.

```
 def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
    return reverse("add-to-cart", kwargs={
    'slug': self.slug
   })

 def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
    return reverse("remove-from-cart", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
   })
```

[urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFyF4.png)

[shop/urls.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGoDq.png)

[models.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzLTX.png)

Comment: you dont have any slud fields in you database soo the page cannot redirect. Slug field cannot be null.

Comment: Thank you. @ngawang13 ,  I will work on this and update my results